# MPM course, implicit updat clarifification

Tags: fluid-dynamics, numerics, simulation

In the [2016 SIGGRAPH notes on MPM](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecffjiang/research/mpmcourse/mpmcourse.pdf) the authors explain how to do an implicit update in section 11.4 throguh by this formula:

[image]

It is not clear to me what the $j$ is over in this case (for eq 202), is it over the velocities of all grid nodes? Or is it just over the velocities of the nodes in a local neighborhood or over something else entirely?

Comment: You can always write it over all, and then reduce it only to the terms where the system entries are non-zero (or as an approximation, where their absolute values are under some theshold).